# Are there general large sieve lower bounds?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given a set of distinct real numbers $(x_j)$ and non-zero complex $(c_j)$, then the large sieve says that

$$\limsup_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\sum_{j}c_j e^{2\pi i n x_j}\right|^2\leq \sum_{j}|c_j|^2.$$

Are there lower bounds saying that

$$\liminf_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\sum_{j}c_j e^{2\pi i n x_j}\right|^2\geq \varepsilon \,\,?$$

I am aware of the paper titled [Lower bounds for expressions of large sieve type](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.1307.pdf), but this deals with a different formulation than the one I am interested in. Namely, it only refers to the dual equality and it includes more terms than I do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look in the literature on Turan's power sum method.  For example there is a chapter on this in Montgomery's Ten Lectures book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the $x_j$'s are distinct modulo $1$ (which is the natural assumption), then
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\sum_{j}c_j e^{2\pi i n x_j}\right|^2=\sum_{j}|c_j|^2.$$
Indeed, let us assume (without loss of generality) that the $x_j$'s lie in $[0,1]$. Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\sum_{j}c_j e^{2\pi i n x_j}\right|^2=\sum_{j,k}c_j\overline{c_k}\sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi in(x_j-x_k)},$$
where the inner sum equals $N$ for $j=k$, and has absolute value not exceeding $\csc(\pi(x_j-x_k))$ for $j\neq k$. The result follows.

**Remark.** The above argument coupled with Corollary 1 in [Montgomery: The analytic principle of the large sieve](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183540922) gives that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\sum_{j}c_j e^{2\pi i n x_j}\right|^2=(N+\Delta)\sum_j|c_j|^2,$$
where $|\Delta|\leq\max_{j\neq k}\|x_j-x_k\|^{-1}.$

Comment: if the OP wants something more precise for the error term, it might make sense to put in the Fejar kernel and use $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(1-\frac{n}{N+1}\right)\left|\sum_{j}c_j e^{2\pi i n x_j}\right|^2.$$

Comment: @JoeSilverman See my added "Remark".